# how to make a div to locate at top corner of another div?

Tags: html, css

Hi i am planning to make a div to place at the top right corner of another div

```
.another
{
   position:fixed;
   padding:09px;
   margin:auto;
   left:25%;
   width:auto;
   height:auto;
   background:#ffffff;
   z-index:999999;
}
.topcorner
{
   float:right;
   position:fixed;
   left:25%;
   z-index:99999999;
}
```

this is my html

```
<div class="another">
    <div class="topcorner">
        i am at top right corner
    </div>
    here is some other content
</div>
```

How to make **topcorner** div to place it in top right corner[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must use a **non-static position** (*static* is the default, then applied when no *position* is specified) to the container (*relative*, *absolute* or *fixed*); then you must apply **absolute position** to the child element.

Using *left*, *top*, *right*, *bottom* you can set the child object's starting points (in your case, *right* and *top*), and eventually the height and the width.

Please note that with *absolute* *position*, the element will be **removed from the flow**, and it would not be recognized as a consistent object in the page anymore; this means that the container content will flow under it how if the child element would not exist.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/pBS68/

CSS Code:

```
.another {
    padding:9px;
    margin:0 auto;
    width:50%;
    height:200px;
    border: 1px solid silver;
    position: relative;
}

.topcorner {    
    position:absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100px;        
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

Use `position:relative` to parent div and `absolute` to child div

```
.another{
    position:relative;
    border:blue solid 1px;
    height:200px;
    background:#ffffff;
}
.topcorner{
    background:red;
    width:30px;
    height:30px;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    right:0;;
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/DNPX6/1/)**

Comment: No, i used **another** div to float so if i give position:relative then it won't be in screen visible.can this be done with position fixed itself?

Comment: See fixed position is meant for browser screen, you cant align the div with fixed to the parent div.

Comment: @raj, you can assign fixed position to the container element, and absolute to the child. That way all the container will be fixed on screen, and the child div will always be in the right corner

Answer (score 5):

try this,

```
.another
{
    position:relative;
    padding:09px;
    margin:auto;
    width:auto;
    height:200px;
    background:#eee;
    z-index:999999;
}
.topcorner
{
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    right:0;
    z-index:99999999;
    width:100px;
    height:auto;
    background:yellow;
}
```

[jsFiddle File](http://jsfiddle.net/dAghE/1/)

Comment: i want **another** div with position:fixed.is that possible can't we change **topcorner** to some other position.Is there any way?

Comment: yes you can use position fixed in the place of absolute and you can change the top corner position with right:0 and top:0, change the 0 as per your need.

Answer (score 2):

Z-Indexs probably not needed there, at least for the .another box.

The inner box won't ever make the exact top right with the padding set on .inner.

Try removing the padding and see if that gets you what you want. Change the Z-Indexes to something sensible, like 0 for .inner and 10 for the other box.

Answer (score 1):

put in your css `Top:*the pixels you want, can also be in minus"-"*;` and `Right:*the pixels you want, can also be in minus"-"*`

This should do it